# Why this property of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^1$ cannot be generalized on the large dimensions

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

In textbook I found the following statement: "Any open set on a line is a disjoint union of finite or countable number of intervals."

I undertand the proof (but cannot understand, why the disjoint union of interval with itself -- this interval. I think that this union must be to consist of set of pairs $(a,i)$, where $i\in I$ -- element of index-set. But the interval is the set of points, not the set of the pairs).

And why this statement cannot be generalize to dimensions greater than $1$?

Comment: Oh, I am found the answer on the first part of question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *can* be generalised: every open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an at most countable union (can be finite too) of disjoint connected open sets.

It just so happens that intervals only make sense in a linear order and the connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are precisely the order-intervals (possibly of infinite length, like $(1,\infty)$).

Comment: So, we say that $x = (x,i)$, where $x\in (a,b)$ and $(a,i) \in (a,b)\sqcup (a,b)$ because the intervals in $\mathbb{R}^{1}$ have linear order?

Comment: @Arsenii that question makes no sense, $x =(x,i)$ is impossible. You're probably referring to some specific proof?

Comment: I am about that disjoint union of $(a,b)$ with itself -- $(a,b)$. May be I am not understand the second part of your answer, sorry

Comment: And not the all open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ -- disjoint union of open balls

Comment: @Arsenii I said they’re disjoint unions of *connected* open sets which can be far more general than open balls.